Google Cloud Storage equivalent of AWS S3 file upload (file buffer)
I'm migrating cloud providers from AWS to GCP. I'm implementing the library @google-cloud/storage using node.js and I'm looking for method equivalence of aws-sdk S3 Bucket API? I already have my configurations ready to implement the GCP client but I haven't found the correct way of uploading a file. This is my current code
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';

export class FileService {
  s3 = new S3();
  private readonly bucket = 'myBucket';

async uploadSingleFile(file: Express.Multer.File, customKey: string) {
    const uploadKey = customKey

    const uploadResult = await this.s3
      .upload({
        Bucket: this.bucket,
        Body: file.buffer,
        Key: uploadKey,
      })
      .promise();
    return { ...uploadResult, name: file.originalname };
  }

I'm just changing cloud providers so I assume there's a similar API method I can call with Google Cloud, something like this I guess
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage'

export class FileService {
  storage = new Storage();
  private readonly bucket = 'myBucket';

async uploadSingleFile(file: Express.Multer.File, customKey: string) {
    const uploadKey = customKey

    const uploadResult = await this.storage
      // I don't know which method from all of the api calls available in the docs
      .uploadFileWithBuffer({
        Bucket: this.bucket,
        Body: file.buffer,
        Key: uploadKey,
      })
      .promise();
    return { ...uploadResult, name: file.originalname };
  }

Also if there's any documentation I can read or any guide on how to migrate my AWS client to Google Cloud that would be really helpful as well.
